# React Native: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Buffer

Tags: react-native

I'm getting the following error in react-native:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Buffer
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

I tried downloading buffer in my react-native app

```
npm install --save buffer
```

and added these lines on top of my index.js and App.js files.

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
global.Buffer = Buffer;
```

But still getting the error, app laods but shows error message.

Comment: When did this error occur ? When upgrading dependencies or enable hermes?

Comment: I was having problems with react native masked view package so I has to change solo kotlin and gradle más the compileSdk version, the error appeared after that

Answer (score 0):

This is a blurry problem mostly related to your working environment and configuration so i suggest few solutions:

1. Double check you are installing the package in the right path of your project as follow:

using npm as follow:

```
npm install --save buffer
```

or using yarn as follow:

```
yarn add buffer
```

2. If you still facing the issue try **to Restart your Metro server** to ensure that the changes are picked up correctly.
3. lastly if any of the provided steps didn’t work consider switching to [react-native-buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-buffer)